# Accessing dynamic variables in R

Tags: r, dynamic-variables

I am trying to use dynamic coding in order to conduct different kinds of analyses in R. I found different suggestions and managed to create dynamic variables, however, little information is available about accessing these variables in similarly dynamic manner.

A little background, I have a data set consisting of individuals with dummy coded groups they belong to, i.e. df$group_A, df$group_b

```
groups <- c("group_A", "group_B", "group_C", "group_D")
df <- data.frame(individual = c("ID_1", "ID_2", "ID_3", "ID_4", "ID_5", "ID_6", "ID_7", "ID_8"),
                 group_A = c(0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1),
                 group_B = c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1),
                 group_C = c(0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0),
                 group_D = c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0))
```

I managed to create a lists of the individuals belonging to each group:

```
for (i in 1:length(groups)){
  assign(paste0(groups[i], "_IDs"), df$individual[df[,groups[i]] == 1])
}
```

However, I struggle to access these lists dynamically for further analysis. Attempts to enter the variable name via

```
paste(groups[i], "_IDs", "")

#or 

paste0(groups[i], "_IDs")
```

did not work but rather recognized it only as a character string. I tried multiple combinations of *noquote()*, *do.call()*, *as.name()*, *get()* but non of them were able to see the string as a variable name.

The same goes for accessing data frame columns dynamically, e.g.:

```
paste0("df$", groups[i])
```

**Any ideas how I can access dynamic variables (and data frame columns)?**

Any suggestions are appreciated. Many thanks in advance. Take care.

Comment: For what it's good for ... try with e.g. `get(paste0(groups[1], "_IDs"))` or for your df with `df[[groups[1]]]`

Comment: You should almost never need to use `assign`, nor `paste` to construct a variable name. The proper solution is to use named lists and vectors for this. In your case, you could assign to `df[[groups[i]]]`. I have yet to see a question asking about this precise usage where `assign` was actually appropriate.

Comment: Thank you very much @stefan for the fast and to the point answers. Much appreciated!

Comment: Thank you very much @KonradRudolph for the fast and to the point answers. Much appreciated!